# Need to configure a JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to configure a jquery pagination plugin, the documentation for which is located [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/extreme-makeover-jpaginator-css3-edition--webdesign-3620), according to which we can set the onPageClicked parameter as under :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initial call
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pagination").jPaginator({ 
        nbPages:64,
        marginPx:5,
        length:8, 
        overBtnLeft:'#over_backward', 
        overBtnRight:'#over_forward', 
        maxBtnLeft:'#max_backward', 
        maxBtnRight:'#max_forward', 
        onPageClicked: function(a,num) { 
            $("#page").html("Page "+num); 
        } 
    });

});

</script>
```

I did the search for this plugin as to how I can set the onPageClicked function according to my needs but could not find any referece, and tried to set it up as under which did not help :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                // Initial call
                \$(document).ready(function(){

                        \$("#pagination").jPaginator({ 
                                nbPages:$lastpage,
                                marginPx:5,
                                length:8, 
                                overBtnLeft:'#over_backward', 
                                overBtnRight:'#over_forward', 
                                maxBtnLeft:'#max_backward', 
                                maxBtnRight:'#max_forward', 
                                onPageClicked: function(a,num) { 
                                        \$(location.href =  'vieword2.pl?page=$page'); 
                                } 
                        });

                });

                </script>
```

For my application I need to configure it for example if I click no.2 on the pagination counter it should load vieword2.pl?page=2.

If someone with jquery knowledge can help me configure it that will be great !!
Many thanks !
Tonya.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, usually the point is to do an ajax call and load the content dynamically into a predefined space..

So this is likely what you need to do.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

                  $("#pagination").jPaginator({ 
                            nbPages:$lastpage,
                            marginPx:5,
                            length:8, 
                            overBtnLeft:'#over_backward', 
                            overBtnRight:'#over_forward', 
                            maxBtnLeft:'#max_backward', 
                            maxBtnRight:'#max_forward', 
                            onPageClicked: function(a,num) { 
                                $('#page').load('vieword2.pl?page='+num); 
                            } 
                    });

            });
```

Or....

```
      onPageClicked: function(a,num) { 
           $.ajax('vieword2.pl',{page:num},function(data){
              $('#page').html(data);
           }); 
      }
```

Or if the page you are actually refreshing is the same page you're on, which I suspect it is....then you were almost there...

```
     onPageClicked: function(a,num) { 
          location.href('vieword2.pl?page='+num);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work, if you can think of other combinations that you think may work that will great !! thanks once again!

Comment: Well theres something you're missing.   Maybe you dont have a #page element?  I dunno.  To know more you would have to post your source to vieword2.pl  (HTML etc)